# Assignment statement inside click event

Tags: angular

I have click event binding on a button like below

```
<button (click)="isClicked()"> Submit <button>

isClicked() {
  clicked = true;
}
```

Is there a way to write the assignment statement 'clicked=true' in the button's click event.
Something like below:

```
<button (click)="{{clicked=true}}"> Submit <button>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
<button (click)="clicked = true"> Submit <button>
```

Just make sure that your `clicked` property is public so it can be accessed from the template.